# Microsoft Botframework upgrade from v3 to v4

Tags: migration, botframework

I have a chatbot running for the past year written with node.js and MS Botframework v3.
Now I need to implement new small functionalities on the chatbot.

I was wondering if I should start migrating to the V4 version right away before implementing the new functionalities? Or if there is a V5 version coming up soon (So that I can leave the bot on the V3 for now and then migrate everything altogether to the V5 version later, to prevent the hassle of double migration)?

However, I did not see news of any V5 on the internet.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, there is no news of botframework v5 on the roadmap yet and we are going strong with v4. I would suggest you to migrate your chatbot from v3 to v4 and then implement the new functionalities.

Hope this helps!!